# Input signal out of range after reinstalling Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, input

Hi i have recently got a second hand HP desktop which was running XP when i got it. When i first brought it home i booted it up on the monitor(hp vs17) that i got with it and everything was fine. However i then wiped the computer and reinstalled windows XP on it. It begins booting and shows the windows XP loading page, but then the screen goes totally blank and displays an error message

" input signal out of range
change settings
1280x1024 - 60HZ "

I have looked at some similar posts however none of them strictly fit my exact problem. Does anyone have any guidance that can help. Have tried on the monitor to adjust settings however it will not allow me to access any menu options. 
I have tried a different monitor hooked up to the tower which works with my other computers, however they give the exact same errors back as the monitor i received with it. Could this me a hardware error with the computer even though it shows some graphical output? If it is hardware problems what can i do and how can i do this without having it booting up and changing things on-screen? Many thanx for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Boot in safe mode, then install the correct video driver.

Comment: it wont even get to the point where can opt to boot in different modes that whats most annoying really. Have tried it on every monitor i can access and all doing exactly the same! I opened the tower up to check inside and unfortunately it is on-board graphics, so couldn't even just pop a new graphics card in it. .

Comment: Has anyone got any further ideas or am i just wasting my time with this PC?

Comment: Thanx very much 4 any help any1 can offa.

Comment: You say it shows the win xp loading page if that's true you should be able to get to safe mode just fine... Safe mode uses low resolution stock video.

Comment: it doesnt go to the page where says like start normally, safe mode, etc. it shows the windows XP sign with a bar below which denotes loading but within seconds goes to black screen with the previously stated error message. However when I ran Dban to wipe it, it booted from the disk to Dban and ran everything fine. Which is why I'm so confused. Could it possibly be the version of XP i am loading as it is an 'unofficial' copy.

Comment: As i previously said when i got the PC it had XP on and I ran it and it never gave any error message, but it was so slow and virus ridden i had to wipe and reinstall. So could it be the copy of XP i am using. Again any help is much appreciated. Thanx